# почему если из 0 в типе unsigned char, если вычесть 1 ,то получится 255?

Tags: c

в чаре 127+1=-128 это легко объясняется. Но никак не могу объяснить почему 0-1 в unsigned получится не -1 , а 255. Надо объяснить конкретно как 00000000-1 получается 11111111

Comment: просто представьте себе, что там есть ещё одна единица слева, то есть. там не 00000000, а 100000000. и все станет на свои места. Хотя, если Вы понимаете, почему 127+1 = -128, то с беззнаковой арифметикой не должно быть проблем.

Comment: Странно. Как раз чар ни разу не очевиден, хотя бы потому что вообще-то есть разные варианты представления отрицательных чисел.

Comment: Вот скажите мне, как в БЕЗЗНАКОВОМ типе может появиться -1?

Comment: *"в чаре 127+1=-128 это легко объясняется"* - во-первых, если слагаемые имеют тип char (знаковый или нет), то результат будет 128, во-вторых это объясняется нетривиально

Comment: KoVadim откуда берется эта еденицца

Comment: Просто интересно, а что должно быть — по-вашему? Ну, а по делу... это 0+(-1), а -1 в виде `unsigned` получается просто как битовая последовательность `char` для этого значения, трактуемая как `unsigned`. Можно для простоты рассматривать это примерно так...

Comment: @user7860670, нет в signed char никаких 128.

Comment: @Qwertiy Полностью с вами согласен.

Comment: Возможно вам станет проще все это понять, если вы узнаете, что сумматор не отличает положительные от отрицательных, он всегда работает с целыми  без знака (причем размером 32 или 64 бита). А интерпретацией получившеся и интересной ему (для char это младшие 8 бит) комбинации бит занимается программист (в случае использования языка компилятор)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Я попробую дать несколько вариантов ответа, они все приблизительно равнозначны.

## Объяснение первое, механическое

Вспомните, как выглядит механический счетчик. Такой могли видеть в старых машинах - он там считает километры (одометр). Или в счетчике воды/электроэнергии. Там несколько колесиков и когда очередное колесо доходит до 9, то оно само превращается в ноль, но при этом прокручивает соседнее.

[image: Счетчик, взято с википедии]
(взято на википедии https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D1%87%D0%B8%D0%BA)

А что будет, если на всех колесиках будет 9? все колесики превратятся в нули.

Но можно рассмотреть и процесс кручения в обратном направлении. Тогда при достижении 000, будет 999. Этот считчик - классический пример беззнаковой переменной.

## Объяснение второе, математическое.

Арифметика беззнаковых чисел работает [как модульная](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_%D0%BF%D0%BE_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D1%83%D0%BB%D1%8E). Для однобайтовых чисел это обычно подразумевает арифметику по модулю 256 (байт обычно 8 бит). В ней (0-1) ≡ 255 (mod 256) и 0 ≡ 256 (mod 256) В си и с++ данное поведение закреплено в стандарте.

## Объяснение третье, процессорное.

Компьютерная техника развивалась постепенно и когда то давно были [арифмометры](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%90%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%84%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%80). А также счетчики на реле на базе двоичной логики.

Представьте себе, что с завода приходят счетчики по 8 реле, то есть, можно считать до 255, а хотелось бы больше. Не проблема - соединим несколько счетчиков вместе (последовательно). И когда один счетчик доходит до 111...111, на нем выставляем 000...000, а на следующий счетчик перебрасываем единицу. И наоборот (Вы спрашивали, где берется эта единица!). Более того, оказалось, что это очень легко сделать чисто схематически - одно реле себе может переключатся 0-1-0-1 (выключено-включено-выключено-включено)